# I want to create a callback, but cannot find connected app under the Apps section

Tags: connected-apps, roles, connected-callback

I am trying to create a callback from salesforce to other platform.
I read some documentation, but I can't find where is the "connected app", is it because my roles issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

search App Manager  in setup and  click  on New Connected App.

you can also  look at salesforce help article.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_create_basics.htm&type=5

Comment: if you take a look my screen shot, you can see I don't have App Manager on the left menu. not sure why not there, even I did follow the documentation, by using search, I can't find App Manager to create new connected app

Comment: My  Bad.  yes   then it is an access issue.check   with your team  who manage this salesforce org.   you need customize application , modify all data   and view setup and configurtion.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322274&type=1

Comment: Connected App is a feature of Sales Cloud. You are working with Marketing Cloud. Callbacks here are only available as part of Transactional Messaging: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createCallback.html